# Why do I need to select the hard disk when my Macbook boots?

Tags: macos, mac

In the past week when booting my Macbook I have had to select the Macintosh Hard Disk before the boot will continue. It is the only disk to choose from and I have never had to do this before. Is also does not happen on every boot.

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Macbook has "forgotten" wich HD is the startup volume. Even if there is only one. Look in the settings and select the HD as startup volume. Then, reboot and look if it is solved.

If not, you could try and reset your PRAM via the open firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "System Preferences => Startup Disk" and see if the proper hard drive is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, to bring up that screen one would hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> (a.k.a. <kbd>option</kbd>) while the computer is booting, before the gray screen appears. It may be that occasionally <kbd>alt</kbd> is getting stuck down or pushed accidentally?